# use a variable out of for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, scope

i tried to run this code. but when i set **x** out of *loop*, the code didn't work.

```
function count(){
        var textbox,x=0;
        textbox = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
        for (var i=0;i<=textbox.length;i++) {
            x += parseInt(textbox[i].value);
        }       
        document.getElementById('total').value=x;   
    }
```

Comment: what is your error message?

Comment: What do you mean with "set out of loop"? https://jsfiddle.net/7msje7vr/

Comment: this code is doing nothing

Comment: You may have problem with for loop, try change condition of for loop `i <= textbox.length` to `i < textbox.length`

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the upper bounds of your for loop is 1 too large. Try:

```
function count(){
        var textboxes,x=0;
        textboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
        for (var i=0;i<textboxes.length;i++) {
            x += parseInt(textboxes[i].value);
        }       
        document.getElementById('total').value=x;   
    }

count();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function fails on both the length of the price inputs and on the potential values within those price inputs.

Using `<=` on the length will produce an error on a non-existent price input "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

I did not like your name of "count" since you were not counting anything so I changed it as well as some variables to make the intent clear.

In addition, values such as "08" would not parse as expected (octal) nor would "fred".

Consider the following inputs:

```
<input class="price" value="33" />
<input class="price" value="3" />
<input class="price" value="-23" />
<input class="price" value="13" />
<input class="price" value="08" />
<input class="price" />
<input class="price" value="fred" />
<input id="total" />
```

Revised code:

```
function totalPrice() {
  var total = 0;
  var prices = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
  var len = prices.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    total += isNaN(parseInt(prices[i].value, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(prices[i].value, 10);
  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = total;
}
totalPrice();
```